# Como puedo extraer solo los 50 primeros nombres?

Tags: java, json, bucle-for, java-swing

Estan dentro de un for y saca todos los nombres, como lo haría para limiatrlo a 50 o cualquier numero, los nombres los saco de un json.

```
public  void tarjetas() throws IOException{
   
        JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.7.1/data/es_ES/champion.json"); 
        Set<String> nombres = json.getJSONObject("data").keySet();

        for (String  nombre: nombres ) {

            JSONObject jsondata = json.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONObject jsname = jsondata.getJSONObject(nombre);
            
            jPanelListadoCampeones.add(new Campeon( jsname.get("name").toString(), jsname.get("title").toString(), nombre));
            
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Deberás mirar la documentación de la API que estás consumiendo para ver cómo gestionan la limitación de la respuesta

Comment: Lo saco de un json directamente, no creo q sea eso, lo saca todos el problema es el tiempo que tarda en colocarlos, y mejor entonces limito los personajes, pero no se como limitar el bucle for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

te voy a dar tres opciones, ya que en este caso se puede hacer con un `for` (menos correcto) o con un `while`, te voy explicando poco a poco:

Ciñéndonos a tu código con un for-each una opción sería esta:

```
public  void tarjetas() throws IOException{

    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.7.1/data/es_ES/champion.json"); 
    Set<String> nombres = json.getJSONObject("data").keySet();
    //Contador de vueltas que contará el número de vuelta y que se irá incrementando hasta 50 y cuando llegue a 50 rompemos el bucle
    Integer contador=1;

    for (String  nombre: nombres ) {

        JSONObject jsondata = json.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONObject jsname = jsondata.getJSONObject(nombre);
        
        jPanelListadoCampeones.add(new Campeon( jsname.get("name").toString(), jsname.get("title").toString(), nombre));
        //Si el contador llega a 50, rompemos bucle, sino... seguimos, pero incrementamos el contador de vueltas
        if(contador==50){
            break;
        }else{
            contador++;
        }   
    }
}
```

Pero esto no es del todo correcto, ya que si no vas a recorrer nunca el array completo, hacer un `for (String  nombre: nombres )` para luego romperlo al de 50 registros, no es una buena práctica, en lugar de eso, se puede usar un `while`, vamos a ello:

```
public  void tarjetas() throws IOException{

    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.7.1/data/es_ES/champion.json"); 
    Set<String> nombres = json.getJSONObject("data").keySet();
    //Definimos un iterador para recorrer el set
    Iterator<String> iterador= nombres.iterator();
    //Contador que se irá incrementando hasta 50 y cuando llegue a 50 rompemos el bucle
    Integer contador=1;
    String nombreOperar;
    // Mientras el iterador tenga registros que recorrer (puede que no haya 50) y el número de registros recorridos sea menos o igual  a 50, hacemos cosas..., después ya no.       
    while (iterador.hasNext() && contador<=50 ) {
        nombreOperar = iterador.next();
        JSONObject jsondata = json.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONObject jsname = jsondata.getJSONObject(nombreOperar );
        
        jPanelListadoCampeones.add(new Campeon( jsname.get("name").toString(), jsname.get("title").toString(), nombreOperar ));
        //Incrementamos el contador
        contador++;

    }
}
```

O de manera alternativa podemos usar un for:

```
public  void tarjetas() throws IOException{

    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.7.1/data/es_ES/champion.json"); 
    Set<String> nombres = json.getJSONObject("data").keySet();
    //Convertimos el Set a ArrayList
    List<String> nombresList= new ArrayList<>(nombres);
    String nombreOperar;
    // Buclamos hasta dar 50 vueltas, estructura del for:
    // for (declaracion de variable a buclar; condición de quedada en el bucle; operación incremental)
    for (int i =0; i<50: i++) {
        nombreOperar = nombresList.get(i)
        JSONObject jsondata = json.getJSONObject("data");
        // Operamos con el elemento del array de la posición i
        JSONObject jsname = jsondata.getJSONObject(nombreOperar );
        
        jPanelListadoCampeones.add(new Campeon( jsname.get("name").toString(), jsname.get("title").toString(), nombreOperar)); 
    }
}
```

Bajo mi humilde opinión, la que más me gusta es la segunda opción, ya que en la tercera hay que hacer una conversión de Set a ArrayList y eso puede ser costoso, y en la primera, es una mala práctica, directamente, la segunda me parece la más eficiente.

Comment: No has usado un *for*, has usado un *for-each*, en este caso un *for* no creo que sea *"mala práctica"*... `for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){}`. Especialmente práctico si defines el límite como una constante en vez de hardcodearlo en el for, queda fácil de leer y obvio

Comment: buena aportación, no había caído, edito respuesta

Comment: pero en la 3a no coge los nombres

Comment: dame un segundo que edito la última parte, que no es correcta, tienes razón (es lo que tiene no probarlo)

Comment: Yaya no te preocupes se agradece la ayuda

Comment: Duda que  me surge, esta parte: `json.getJSONObject("data").keySet()`  tiene algo para recibir un ArrayList en lugar de un Set?, porque si no es así, la última solución no la veo viable, porque convertir el Set a un arrayList es más costoso que hacer un `while`

Comment: pero el while tampoco coge los nombres, no tengo nada aparte para recibir el arrayList

Comment: Listo, ya tienes ambas partes funcionales, tanto la segunda como la tercera, es que no puedo probarlo exactamente todo pues no tengo el  JSONObject instalado, pero así estaría correctamente

Comment: La ultima cosa, lo prometo,  entonces en vez de nombre por q lo cambio en esta linea:
`
jPanelListadoCampeones.add(new Campeon( jsname.get("name").toString(), jsname.get("title").toString(), nombre));
`
el nombre ese ultimo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136780/discussion-between-chikebox-and-jose-antonio-rm).